# Multiple aggregate function for mysql. like SUM

Tags: mysql, sql, select, max, aggregate

How can I multiple numbers from table to one result like SUM() does?

In "table1" I have column "number1" with these values:

```
table1.number1
--------------
1  
2  
3
```

I try this sql:

```
SELECT @multiple := @multiple number1 as mul  
FROM table1
```

and I got this:

```
mul
---  
1  
2  
6
```

But I need just the last row with the value: 6
without using `ORDER DESC`

Comment: You could just use `MAX(@multiple := @multiple * number1)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT MAX(@multiple := @multiple * number1) AS mul  
FROM table1, (SELECT @multiple:=1) a;
```

Comment: Well, the thing is - it's unstable. If your table will contain something like `1E100`, `1E100`, `1E-100`, `1E-100` - you'll get overflow while whole result is ok (it's `1`, obviously)

Comment: @AlmaDo: Not applicable if all values are ≥ 1.

Comment: But that's not specified in question